# Shut down a script when it's detached from the terminal without kill

Tags: bash

I have a bash script task with following requirement:

"Script must be easy to shut down when it's detached from the terminal without having to resort to ps, pgrep, pkill and their like"

With my limited knowledge (and search), I couldn't see any method. Do you have any idea what they are referring to?

Comment: maybe using traps & signals over the ID of the script ; but keep in mind there are not so much methods because it is not needed as far as all you mention ps/pgrep/pkill/kill and so on are just very satisfying methods & unix standard

Comment: @francoisP well its actually a task for job interview which is not very high level position. now im assuming that they just put that requirement for test me lol

Answer (score 2):

This is a common design requirement for [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) processes, where you want them running in the background most of the time but occasionally need to interact with them (e.g. kill them). In theory you could manually do a `ps`, `pgrep` etc. and send signals to whatever PID you find, but it's often inconvenient for users to have to do that.

The traditional way to do this sort of thing is via a [PID file](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/pid-file), which is a file that your background process creates at a consistent place in the filesystem so that other processes or scripts can communicate with it. You can put this wherever you want, but they're often located at:

- `/run/<name>.pid` for system-level processes. (e.g. [`lightdm`](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm) on my machine)
- `/run/user/<UID>/<name>.pid` for user-level processes (e.g. [`rofi`](https://github.com/davatorium/rofi) on my machine)

*This can have a side benefit of ensuring you only run one instance of the script at a time if that's desirable. If you want to run more than one, you'll have to figure out a naming or locating scheme to accommodate that.*

The usual paradigm is to have your daemon script (e.g. `myscript`) create this file when it starts and write its own PID to the file, and then have a separate controller script (common naming convention would be `myscriptctl`) that will read the file and, in your case, kill the associated process. In most shells, including bash, you can use the [special `$$` variable](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID) to get the current process ID. I've put an example script and controller below:

---

`myscript.sh`:

```
# Create PID file
PIDFILE=/run/user/$UID/myscript.pid
echo $$ > $PIDFILE

# Do whatever your script should do in the background
while true; do
    echo "Hello world!";
    sleep 5;
done
```

`myscriptctl.sh`:

```
# Read PID file
PIDFILE=/run/user/$UID/myscript.pid
PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)

# Interact with that process
if [ $1 = "kill" ]; then
    kill $PID
    rm $PIDFILE
fi
```

Comment: Which uses kill. OTOH if the target script is also running in a loop it could poll the existence of file and, on that basis, decide to terminate early. OTOH this funcionality is exactly the kind of problem signals should be used for.

Comment: Oh interesting, I interpreted the question as in "not requiring the end-user to manually run pgrep and kill", which seems like a common requirement. If the question is instead asking "how to end a script without sending a signal", than that's a very strange ask, but yeah any manner of polling or monitoring could achieve that.

Comment: @AlexaSchor thanks for your good explanation. It was for a job interview, still today the question hold the mystery of what they were actually asking :) But i've learned a nice point from your answer